# Runas Password in Batchfile

Tags: batch-file, runas

i want to run a batchfile with a runas command in it.
Is it possible to link the password in Batch file?
For example: runas /profile /user\domain PASSWORD
thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: What do you mean by `link`?

Comment: maybe check out `net use` [here](https://ss64.com/nt/net-use.html).

Comment: Read `runas /?` (there is no _password_ parameter in the command line). _Enter user's password only when prompted._

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**An Alternate Solution**

It looks as though `runas` does not allow what you want (without severely compromising security... see below). However, there is a third-party utility called `PsExec` which *does* allow this. From the [Sysinternals PsExec page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec):

> ```
> Usage: psexec [\\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file\]][-u user [-p psswd][-n s]
>               [-r servicename][-h][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i [session]]
>               [-c executable [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d]
>               [-<priority>][-a n,n,...] cmd [arguments]
> ```

(*Note: the idea to use `PsExec` came from Lauren7060's answer to [this question on Spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/368007-runas-batch-including-password)*).

So, something like:

```
psexec -u MYUSER -p MYPASSWORD MYBATCH.BAT
```

should do what you want.

---

**What Doesn't Work**

As you found, `runas` normally prompts the user to enter the password. Interestingly, you can either pipe data into `runas`:

```
echo password | runas ...
```

or redirect input from a file:

```
runas ... < PASSWORD.TXT
```

and `runas` will *not* prompt for a password. However, I could **not** get `runas` to accept the password as valid, however I formatted the data. In the latter case (redirecting from a file), I tried both with and without a line-ending, but neither worked. My *guess* is that the pipe/redirect is enough to stop `runas` *prompting* for a password, but that it doesn't *really* read anything from `stdin`. This is partially supported by [this article on the Tech Torials website](https://techtorials.me/windows/using-runas-with-a-password/) that describes a method where you *can* use `runas` without it prompting for a password, but ***only*** if you set the account's password to an empty string.

Comment: *N. B.:* `echo password | runas ...` would write `password` + _space_ into the pipe…

Comment: @aschipfl Aware of that, and there are ways of avoiding adding the space when needed. The problen is/was that `runas` wasn't reading from the pipe. Reflecting on things while typing this reply, my suspicion is that it flushes `stdin` (a not unreasonable thing to do if it's connected to a keyboard, to prevent erroneous typeahead), thus consuming and discarding anything piped-in.

Answer (score 1):

I have also finding the way how to do this.But unfortunately i cant find any way how to do this on internet.Then i discovered(from own) one way from which you can do it without using any third party software.You can do this by using batch scripting and vbs.
First I have created a vbs file to send password to command prompt and press enter automatically.I have pause script for 1s so that password can be entered after running runas command.
Simply Create a file like this:-

::Creating vbs file to give password to runas command:-

```
 echo Set x=CreateObject("wscript.shell")>C:\users\%username%\Desktop\pass.vbs
        echo wscript.sleep 1000>>C:\users\%username%\Desktop\pass.vbs
        echo x.sendkeys "<password of user>">>C:\users\%username%\Desktop\pass.vbs
        echo x.sendkeys "{enter}">>C:\users\%username%\Desktop\pass.vbs
        start C:\users\%username%\Desktop\pass.vbs
        runas /user:<Username for which you want> "<File that you want to run>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two files: *vbs*, and *batch* file.

InputPass.vbs:

```
Set w=CreateObject("wscript.shell")
w.sendkeys "<PASSWORD>"
w.sendkeys "{enter}"
```

StartProg.bat:

```
start InputPass.vbs
runas /user:<ADMIN OR ANY OTHER USERNAME WITH ADMIN RIGHTS> "<PROGRAM TO EXECUTE>"
```

After that you can execute StartProg.bat, and there you have it! :D